# How to add the index of every uppercase character in a string in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, uppercase

I'm trying to create a class `Capslock` which will take in a string and return an `int[]` of the indexes of the character in uppercase. Here is my code so far:

```
public class Capslock {
    public static int[] allCapLocations(String st) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < st.length(); x++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(x)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        int[] j = new int[count];
        for (int u = 0; u < st.length(); u++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(u)) {
                j.add(u);
            }
```

I'm struggling to understand how to add `u` into my `int[] j`. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: You need an additional `int cursor = 0;`, then you can `j[cursor++] = u;` ..but better: do it in a list (mutable size;)(with one loop)..and return list.toArray();)

Comment: Do you get any `count` greater than zero? I ask this because you are checking if `x` is upper case, but `x` is the index, **not** the value at that index. Read about how to access elements of an array… Reading it will reveal how to add elements (hint: arrays don't have the method `add`).

Comment: Yes, 1st loop also does not, what it supposed to...!? :)) It should "analyze" the caracters of `st` not the "indices"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read from the comments, there are several ways to get the desired results. **Some** of them:

**Approach 1**

1. count := count of the uppercase letters
2. Create an array of length count
3. Set each element in this array to the index of the corresponding uppercase letter

In code:

```
public static int[] allCapLocations(String st) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
        char ch = st.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    int[] uppercaseIndices = new int[count];
    int cursor = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < st.length(); index++) {
        char ch = st.charAt(index);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            uppercaseIndices[cursor] = index;
            cursor++;
        }
    }
    return uppercaseIndices;
}
```

**Approach 2**

1. Create an array of length text.length()
2. Count the uppercase letters, and while counting, update the array.
3. Return a copy of the partial array ranging from 0 to count - 1.

```
public static int[] allCapLocations(String st) {
    int[] uppercaseIndices = new int[st.length()];
    int count = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < st.length(); index++) {
        char ch = st.charAt(index);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            uppercaseIndices[count] = index;
            count++;
        }
    }

    return java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(uppercaseIndices, 0, count);
}
```

**Approach 3**

1. list := an empty List
2. Count the uppercase letters, and while counting, add elements to list.
3. Return list.toArray()

Drawback: as List uses complex types, the wrapper type `java.lang.Integer` instead of the primitive type `int` is used and returned by toArray(). That is, you have to either change the return type to `Integer[]` or convert the array.

```
public static Integer[] allCapLocations(String st) {
    List<Integer> uppercaseIndices = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < st.length(); index++) {
        char ch = st.charAt(index);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            uppercaseIndices.add(index);
        }
    }
    return uppercaseIndices.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

**Approach 4**

1. Use a stream of indices in the range between 0 and st.length()
2. Filter the stream to retain only those indices that point to an uppercase character in st.
3. Return an array from the resulting stream.

```
public static int[] allCapLocations(String st) {
    return IntStream.range(0, st.length())
            .filter(index -> Character.isUpperCase(st.charAt(index)))
            .toArray();
}
```